# Allocate a new bool array pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm curious how you go about allocating a new boolean array pointer in c++. I did some looking around but couldn't find anything that is similar to how I've learned to allocate new pointers.

To allocate a new int pointer I have learned to do

```
int * intPointer = new int;
```

What would be the proper way for a boolean array? I've tried:

```
bool * boolArr[] = new [] bool;
```

but I get the error "expected type-specifier before '[' token

Comment: You're confusing *declaring* the pointer, with allocating new space in the heap with `new`.

Comment: You're correct, I was using the wrong terminology. I'll fix that in the title and question for future reference. Thanks for pointing that out...no pun intended.

Comment: Thanks. But, still, you don't "allocate a bool array pointer", you just allocate a bool array and get a pointer to it.

Comment: Your C++ course is probably outdated. `new` and `delete` belong in constructors and destructors of classes. And for the most common uses we already have suitable classes, such as `std::vector<>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to dynamically allocate an array of booleans, you need to do

```
bool *arr = new bool[10];
```

You have to specify the array size.

The syntax for static allocation is

```
bool arr[10];
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for! Didn't realize I had to specify the array size.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to dynamically allocate an array of booleans, you need to do

```
std::vector<bool> arr;
arr.reserve(10);
```

You don't have to specify the size.

The syntax for static allocation is

```
std::array<bool, 10> arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Dynamically** allocating an Boolean array of size n

```cpp
bool* arr = new bool[n];
```

**Static** allocation.

```cpp
bool arr[n];
```

dynamic array is allocated through **Heap Memory** which is better for situations where array size may be large.

Ideally, you are also supposed to **Manually delete the dynamically allocated array space** by using

```cpp
delete[] arr
```

deleting allocated space may be taken as optional in casual use cases, but is definitely encouraged as a Professional Practise.